# How can the "Echo" stay there what i submitted?

Tags: php, post, echo

When i click the submit button and i see the "echo", but when i refresh the page the "echo" disappaer.

Here it is my script:

```html
<?php
    $asktext = $_POST['asktext'];

    if(isset($_POST['askbtn'])) {
     echo $asktext;
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <p align="right"><input type="submit" name="loginbtn" value="Log in">
        <form action ="" method="post">
            <p align="middle">
            <textarea name="asktext" style="width: 600px; height: 150px; resize: none"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="submit"name="askbtn" value="Ask!" style="width: 600px;">
            </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because it's a NEW request?! HTTP is very forgetful! It forgets about you every new request!

Comment: When do you close your form?

Answer (score 1):

You can echo the variable back into the textarea, but make sure to escape the html special characters.  Also, check that the post variable is set before trying to read it. And close your form.

```
<?php
$asktext = '';
if(isset($_POST['askbtn'])) 
{
    $asktext =  $_POST['asktext'];
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<p align="right"><input type="submit" name="loginbtn" value="Log in">
<form action ="" method="post">
<p align="middle">
<textarea name="asktext" style="width: 600px; height: 150px; resize: none"><?echo htmlspecialchars($asktext); ?></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="askbtn" value="Ask!" style="width: 600px;"
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you refreshing the page or re-accessing it?
You code should work fine when submitted/upon refresh but if you are hitting Enter to 'refresh' you are losing the post request.